# Excel VBA Code to save each iteration of List in a separate PDF File

Tags: excel, vba

I have almost no background in VBA coding. My excel sheet has a data validation list in cell G4.

Depending on the list value selected, the cells below use index match to get values from another sheet.

I need to figure out how to save a pdf version of this tab for every single list value.

This is the code I've pieced together so far, but isn't working. The error message says "Automation Error : File Name, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect". Thank you so much for your help!!!!!

```
Sub Run_Through_data_Validation()
Dim dataCellVal As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim V As Range



   Set dataCellVal = Worksheets("Summary_Page").Range("g4")

   Set inputRange = Evaluate(dataCellVal.Validation.Formula1)

For Each V In inputRange
    dataCellVal = V.Value
    
    Worksheets("Summary_Page").Range("g4").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=dataCellVal
  
Next V


End Sub
```

Comment: That sounds like the value in `Worksheets("Summary_Page").Range("g4")` is not a valid filename.

Comment: I agree. I don't know what to change it so that every single value of the list is stored in a new PDF file.